# Identify UIImages Individually

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, tags, uiimage

I've got an app where multiple UIImages can be added to the view. Those images can then be dragged around the screen. How can I check which image has been dragged and then save *that* image's coordinates to a file and no other UIImage in the same view. I need a way of tagging each UIImage if possible to separate them out and identify them each individually. Hopefully this makes sense!

This is how I'm adding each UIImage to the view:

```
CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(activeView.center.x - 50, activeView.center.y - 50, 200, 200);
imageResizableView = [[SPUserResizableView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"galaxy.jpg"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
imageResizableView.contentView = imageView;
imageResizableView.delegate = self;
[activeView addSubview:imageResizableView];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIImageView`s are UIView subclasses, so have a `tag` property. Set that for each image, then when you want that one image `[self.subViews viewWithTag:number];` to find it.

EDIT: If I understand this, there are many UIImageViews, but multiple imageViews may show the same image.

Assuming that, then you partition the tag's 32 bits to say 16 bits upper as the unique imageView number, and the lower 16 are the image number. You will then need to iterate through all subviews looking for the image. You can use macros to make this easier:

```
#define TAG_NUMBER(imageViewNum, imageNum) ((imageViewNum << 16) | imageNum)
#define IMAGE_FROM_TAG(tag) (tag & 0xFFFF)
etc
```

when you want to find all imageviews showing that image:

```
for(UIVIew *view in self.subviews) {
if(![view isKindOf:[UIIMageView class]]) continue;

int imageNum = IMAGE_FROM(view.tag);
if(imageNum == theOneIwant) {
  save frame of "view"
}
}
```

Comment: But if I set a tag on imageView, every image's tag would be set to that tag. I need a way of setting a tag for each individual UIImage, not all of them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **tag** `property` on UIVIew.

As per mentioned in the official [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html):

> **tag** An integer that you can use to identify view objects in your application.
>
> **@property(nonatomic) NSInteger tag** Discussion The default value is 0. You can set the value of this tag and use that value to identify the view later.

Comment: But if I set a tag on imageView, every image's tag would be set to that tag. I need a way of setting a tag for each individual UIImage, not all of them.

Comment: :-) If you access your imageView through an index on a structure you can use this index as an identifier

Comment: How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Where do store all your imageviews?? you must have a data structure for that no?

Comment: How do you mean 'stored'? I just add them via [activeView addSubview:imageResizableView]; to the view.

Comment: Well then each time you add them to a view assign a number to the tag

Answer (score 1):

If integer tags are good enough, then use the `tag` property which already exists for UIViews.

However, if you want something more, you can use `obj_setAssociatedObject` to add a tagName property to UIView.

```
@interface UIView (tagName)
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *tagName;
@end
```

--

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UIView (tagName)
static char tagNameKey[1];

- (NSString*)tagName {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, tagNameKey);
}

- (void)setTagName:(NSString *)tagName {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, tagNameKey, tagName, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC);
}
@end
```

which can then be used like so...

```
NSString *imageName = @"galaxy.jpg";
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
imageView.tagName = imageName;
```

and later...

```
NSString *imageName = imageView.tagName;
```

**EDIT**

Of course, you can add whatever you want, for example to mimic `viewWithTag`

```
- (UIView*)viewWithTagName:(NSString *)tagName {
    if ([self.tagName isEqualToString:tagName]) {
        return self;
    }

    UIView *result = nil;
    for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {
        if ((result = [view viewWithTagName:tagName]) != nil) {
            return result;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Or just make a subclass of UIImageView with an identifier; much easier than associated objects.

Comment: Agreed.  Since there is a lookup cost to associated objects, the subclass mechanism should be preferred.  Unless... you want to use this in the general case of UIView, similar to the built-in integer tag.  Then there is that ongoing debate about whether tags are a good thing...  or associated objects in general... or categories... or...